# Two WMs simultaneously

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, i3, display-manager, steam

I want to use two Windows Managers simultaneously.
As I know that using two ttys for this isn't going to work (I'm on Arch and systemd-logind revokes access to hardware when switching), I am searching for another method to do this.

Maybe even a completely different approach to my idea, which is to use i3wm and steamOS-compositor simultaneously. I don't want a KVM, as I don't have two graphics cards. Also, I absolutely am against dual-booting, as this is my current setup and takes way too much time. Maybe relogging is an option, but only as a last resort.

Comment: BTW, using two tty's work fine for that without `systemd`...

Comment: I need and like systemd, so changing my whole workflow and Distro is not an option.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that "revoking access to hardware" is not something Linux-intrinsic. Possibly you can configure `systemd` to not do that. In the end, for two WMs, you need two X servers, be it on different tty's, or one of them Xephyr, or both controlled by `systemd` without a tty, or whatever other flavour. No way around that.

Comment: As I already wrote "systemd-logind revokes access", I thought I made it clear enough that I know why that happens. I do not want to screw with systemd though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `Xephyr`:

```
$ Xephyr :1 -ac -screen 800x600
$ DISPLAY=:1 startfluxbox
```